# Problem in animate scrollTop for multi div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div with id (# left-div - # right-div). In # left-div i have multi div with id and # left-div's  overflow-y is scroll. In # right-div i have multi button with id. I want after click on each button, # left-div scroll to show Specific div that button clicked. I use jquery. How to create this action?

This is my code:

```
<div id="#left-div">
   <div id="div1"></div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
   <div id="div3"></div>
   <div id="div4"></div>
</div>

<div id="#right-div">
   <button id="btn1"></button>
   <button id="btn2"></button>
   <button id="btn3"></button>
   <button id="btn4"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is have the same class for a `div` and it's associated `button`.when the button is clicked you can get elements which have that class and scroll to the first element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var className = element.attr("class");
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    $("html, body").animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $(x[0]).offset().top
      },
      2000
    );
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: green;
}

#div4 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#left-div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 JS -->
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div id="left-div">
            <div id="div1" class="element1">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus,
              natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae
              impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti
              aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus
              rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et obcaecati
              quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque, corrupti?
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit
              asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid
              repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit
              deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor,
              sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta
              doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et
              obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque,
              corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Odit asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi.
            </div>
            <div id="div2" class="element2">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus,
              natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae
              impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti
              aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus
              rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et obcaecati
              quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque, corrupti?
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit
              asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid
              repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit
              deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor,
              sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta
              doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et
              obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque,
              corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Odit asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi.
            </div>
            <div id="div3" class="element3">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus,
              natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae
              impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti
              aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus
              rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et obcaecati
              quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque, corrupti?
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit
              asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid
              repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit
              deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor,
              sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta
              doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et
              obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque,
              corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Odit asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi.
            </div>
            <div id="div4" class="element4">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus,
              natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae
              impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti
              aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus
              rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et obcaecati
              quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque, corrupti?
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit
              asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea ullam debitis qui aliquid
              repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam pariatur odio fuga suscipit
              deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor,
              sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ullam modi soluta
              doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime minima provident et
              obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde odit facere. Eaque,
              corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Odit asperiores quae repellendus rerum placeat voluptates iste sit
              dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id tempora dolores, velit nihil
              incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus modi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, natus rerum laborum ea
              ullam debitis qui aliquid repudiandae impedit. Praesentium totam
              pariatur odio fuga suscipit deleniti aliquid tenetur temporibus
              maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Porro ullam modi soluta doloribus rerum vero natus autem, maxime
              minima provident et obcaecati quisquam consequatur numquam unde
              odit facere. Eaque, corrupti? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit asperiores quae repellendus
              rerum placeat voluptates iste sit dolores dignissimos tenetur? Id
              tempora dolores, velit nihil incidunt debitis! Tempora, accusamus
              modi.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <div id="right-div">
            <button id="btn1" class="element1">Bt1</button>
            <button id="btn2" class="element2">Btn2</button>
            <button id="btn3" class="element3">Btn3</button>
            <button id="btn4" class="element4">Btn4</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```