# Scroll to elem with custom tag/attribute

Tags: javascript, scroll, queryselector

I am trying to scroll to an elem with a custom tag and attribute

I have the following code :

```
<jmnode class="root" nodeid="Ancre-1">Test</jmnode>

<button class="btn" onclick="scroller('Ancre-1');">Voir</button>

<script>
    function scrollToElem(elem) {
        window.scrollTo(elem.offsetTop, 0);

    }

    function scroller (ancre) {
        var elem = document.querySelector("jmnode[nodeid='" + ancre + "']");
        scrollToElem(elem);
    }

</script>
```

This is what I did :

1. Register onclick event to function scroller.
2. Function scroller finds the elem based on the parameter provided and
   executes function scrollToElem which is supposed to make the scroll
   happen.

This does not work, no error is raised and the functions are indeed executed, so I would guess my scrolling function is broken.

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60793806/9871756)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, what you recommend is the following ?     $("html, body").animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $(x[0]).offset().top
      },
      2000
    );

Comment: yeah instead of passing `x[0]` you would just pass `elem` and that should work

Comment: It moves to the bottom of the datatable in which I have the buttons appearing. But the destination (nodejm with nodeid attribute) is way outside (below) of the datatable (and other containers), is that expected ?

Comment: No it isn't it should scroll to the start of the destination, could you provide a `codesandbox` or something so that i may take a look

Comment: It's pretty complicated because I have so much libraries being used but I believe it may have something to do with the fact the selected element (with a custom tag/attribute) is generated via JS after the page has loaded. Could that be an issue ?